# Reflex and complex

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

My prefix is a part of a reflex
My infix is very complex
my suffix is more than two
but the whole thing is not true

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My prefix is a part of a reflex

> the letter L is part of 'a ref**L**ex'

My infix is very complex

> $i = \sqrt{-1}$ which is very complex

my suffix is more than two

> $e \approx 2.71828$ which is more than two

but the whole thing is not true

What am I?

> a lie